# Generic parameter in method for generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics, methods

The public method addToFront is supposed to take a generic parameter (T) that is then added to the front of an empty array list. I don't know the syntax for the generic parameter and cannot find anything online for help.

```java
public class RandomStuffContainer<T extends Comparable<T>>
{

  ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
    
  public  void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
  }
        
  public void addToFront()
  {
    array.add(0, T);
  } 

}
```

I just need help with putting in the generic parament for addToFront.

Comment: You need a _value_ of type T to put in the list.  T is a type, not a value.

Comment: Something like: `public void addToFront(T value) { array.add(0, value); }`

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add an object of type T in method addToFront to your array List. The first thing you need to think of the parameter input to the method. Something like this,
addToFront(T obj). And inside the method, you can array.add(0, obj);
The parameter in addToFront obj type should be similar to the ArrayList.